# Json field that can be string or bool into struct

Tags: json, go

I am using an API, which returns a field that is sometimes a boolean, sometimes a string.

like this:

```
{
   "unstable":true,
   "unstable_reason":"ANY_REASON"
}
```

and

```
{
   "unstable":false
   "unstable_reason":false
}
```

the struct looks like this:

```
        ...
        Unstable       bool   `json:"unstable"`
        UnstableReason string `json:"unstable_reason,string"`
        ...
```

When trying to use this, I get the following error:

`panic: json: invalid use of ,string struct tag, trying to unmarshal unquoted value into string`

On the other hand, when using `bool` for `UnstableReason`, an error occurs aswell.

When removing `,string`, I get this error:
`panic: json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field .data.prices.unstable_reason of type string`

The field is not relevant for my purposes, so if there is a way to just let it be `nil`, this would also be fine.

I have no impact on the API.

Any Ideas? I am relatively new to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use interface{} type like as:

```
type YourMessage struct {
    Unstable       bool        `json:"unstable"`
    UnstableReason interface{} `json:"unstable_reason"`
}

func (m YourMessage) UnstableReasonAsString() string {
    return fmt.Sprint(m.UnstableReason)
}

...
m1 := &YourMessage{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(messageJson), m1); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error", err)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Unstable Reason=", m1.UnstableReasonAsString())
}
```